# Unable to get the package dependencies for google_maps_flutter 1.1.1

Tags: android, flutter, google-maps, google-maps-flutter

I am integrating Google Map in my flutter project and after adding the package **google_maps_flutter 1.1.1** inside my **pubspec.yaml** and clicking **pub get** , I am getting such error:

```
The plugin `flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle` doesn't have a main class defined in G:\New folder\Shortedcubesolutions Softwares\Flutter SDK windows 1.20.4\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-1.0.11\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle\FlutterAndroidLifecyclePlugin.java or G:\New folder\Shortedcubesolutions Softwares\Flutter SDK windows 1.20.4\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-1.0.11\android\src\main\kotlin\io\flutter\plugins\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle\FlutterAndroidLifecyclePlugin.kt. This is likely to due to an incorrect `androidPackage: io.flutter.plugins.flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle` or `mainClass` entry in the plugin's pubspec.yaml.
If you are the author of this plugin, fix the `androidPackage` entry or move the main class to any of locations used above. Otherwise, please contact the author of this plugin and consider using a different plugin in the meanwhile. 
Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have already tried the older versions of this package but getting the same issue.
Please help me out !

Here is my **pubspec.yaml** code:

```
 name: thehelpdesk
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  introduction_screen: ^1.0.7
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4
  hexcolor: ^1.0.6
  curved_navigation_bar: ^0.3.4
  email_validator: '^1.0.5'
  validate: ^1.7.0
  dio: 3.0.10
  pin_code_fields: ^5.0.1
  geolocator: ^6.1.14
  google_maps_flutter: 0.5.21+17


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3
  sqflite: ^1.3.0
  path_provider: ^1.6.24

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/sp_screen.png
    - assets/images/reg_logo.png
    - assets/images/email@_icon.png
    - assets/images/mobile_icon.png
    - assets/images/arrow_icon.png
    - assets/images/Invoice.png
    - assets/images/cake.png
    - assets/images/calender.png
    - assets/images/Reminder.png
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
   - family: Poppins
     fonts:
       - asset: fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf
       - asset: fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf
       - asset: fonts/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf

   - family: Roboto
     fonts:
       - asset: fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf

  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Comment: Post your `pubspec.yaml` file content

Comment: @dm_tr , posted

Comment: I mean the entire code not only the dependencies section

Comment: Here I am using more than a year older google_maps_flutter version